# The merge option in Firestore set() doesn't work in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore

```
const data = {name : myName};
fileRef.set(data, { merge: true });
```

Gives following error:

```
Invalid use of type "undefined" as a Firestore argument.
```

This is exactly how it is used in the Firebase documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data), and how others are using it in examples online. It does however work perfectly for me when I don't use the option argument and just do:

```
fileRef.set(data);
```

I am using the firebase-admin npm package.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you do a `console.log`of `data` before calling the `.set()` method? I think your problem may be that `myName` variable is undefined.

Comment: No that's fine. I didn't include all of my code. As I mentioned, just passing in `data` works fine, so its not that.

Comment: Are you doing this from Cloud functions?

Comment: Is `myName` a single string or a complex object?

Answer (score 4):

The option to merge data is not yet available for Node.js. Instead, you can call the update method to do the same. If the node does not exists it will be created

```
fileRef.update(data);
```

Comment: apparently this is stated as a comment in the Node.js tab `// The option to merge data is not yet available for Node.js. Instead, call the
// update method and pass the option to create the document if it's missing.` https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out that my `data` argument was the problem. One of the entries was in fact, `undefined`. Thanks @mtflud, and sorry for disregarding your answer initially.

NodeJs was fine with `{merge : true}` once I fixed my `data` argument and everything works correctly now.